# How to work with lazy initialization? [LazyInitializationException]

Tags: java, hibernate, lazy-loading

To fetch lazy object, you need to invoke `Hibernate.initialize(proxy)` e.g. in your service class:

```
public <R> R fetchLazy(T entity, Function<T,R> proxyMapper) {
    entity = ensureEntityHasOpenedSession(entity);
    R proxy = proxyMapper.apply(entity);
    Hibernate.initialize(proxy);
    return proxy;
}
```

Outside of the service scope one would need to call:

```
AnotherEntity another = service.fetchLazy(entity, Entity::getAnotherEntity);
```

Now, the question is why this works:

```
another.getId();
```

while subsequent call does not:

```
entity.getAnotherEntity().getId(); // LazyInitializationException
```

Has not been `AnotherEntity` stored in `Entity` after first fetch? Do I always need to call

```
service.fetchLazy(entity, Entity::getAnotherEntity).getSomething();
```

If so, does `Hibernate.initialize(Object)` return cached proxy at second call or there is always another database access (query execution)?

**EDIT**

I'm using JPA annotations on private class fields in combination with [lombok](https://projectlombok.org/)'s [@Getter](https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter) [@Setter](https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter) annotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably using JPA field access i.e. you annotated the Java fields of your entity classes rather than the getters. This is a known limitation of field access in Hibernate. The only way to avoid the exception or explicit initialization is by using property access instead.

Also see the following JIRA issues for further information

- https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-5501
- https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9085

Comment: +1 didn't know there is a difference between field and method annotation functionality. Can you provide some citations about field/method annotation impact on lazy initialization (I would gladly accept the answer)?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with subsequent call was implementation of `ensureEntityHasOpenedSession(entity)` method in combination with [access strategy](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/chapters/domain/access.html) as pointed by @ChristianBeikov.

To be more specific, I have implemented mentioned method as `entityManager.find(entityClass, entityId)` which returns **new instance of the entity**. As a result, `AnotherEntity` proxy was initialized in new entity instance, while subsequent call was manipulating with old entity instance. Since I was using **field annotations**, any method call has led to proxy initialization as stated in [JPA implementation patterns: Field access vs. property access](https://xebia.com/blog/jpa-implementation-patterns-field-access-vs-property-access/):

> Hibernate’s lazy loading implementation always initializes a lazy
>   proxy when any method on that proxy is invoked. The only exception to
>   this is the method annotated with the @Id annotation when you use
>   property access. But when you use field access there is no such method
>   and Hibernate initializes the proxy even when invoking the method that
>   returns the identity of the entity.

hence `LazyInitializationException` (old entity with closed session + trying to initialize proxy).